# What is the role of empirical risk minimization in support vector machines?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

While learning about SVMs, I have come across a term called empirical risk minimization (EMR). I have learnt about this in [this paper by Smola and Schölkopf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.114.4288) but failed to understand what is the role of empirical risk minimization in support vector machines? And please also tell me how sequential minimal optimization implements EMR in the LibSVM package?

> Smola, Alex J., and Bernhard Schölkopf. "A tutorial on support vector
>   regression." Statistics and computing 14.3 (2004): 199-222.